# SSRS Bids default zoom on report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, bids

When I open my report, the default zoom is 100%, for the purpose of my report, the user needs to look at 75% and I am worried that every time they run the report they will have to manually adjust this. I can imagine that could get quite tedious. Is there a way in which I can tell each report part what percentage the zoom should default to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rc: Zoom is the parameter to be used to set the Zoom level in Reports.
For more information on this u can refer this site
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188712.aspx

so you could use something like 
http://www.myserver.com/reportserver?/AdventureWorks 2008 Sample Reports/Company Sales 2008&rc:Zoom=75